# Back arrow in tool bar in order to go to previous activity

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp

I have implemented a chat activity and a search icon to search for texts. After entering the text, it will direct to another activity in order to display the texts. Now, I want to add a back arrow in my action bar or tool bar in order to go to the previous activity.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var bundle: Bundle ? = intent.extras
        query = bundle?.getString("query") as String
        setSupportActionBar(chatSearchToolbar)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_search)
        loadQueryList(realm, query)
    }
```

chatSearchToolBar is my tool bar in XML file.
How do I implement it?

Comment: That's java, this is kotlin

Comment: So it would be... `supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` and in `onOptionsItemSelected()` You handle menuItemId by checking if it is `android.R.id.home` (or not handling it but declaring parentActivity in AndroidManifest `android:parentActivityName="..."`).